# Converting Data from @material-table to @mui/x-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, promise, material-ui, datagrid, material-table

I am struggling with converting Rows data to mui/x-data-grid. As of now, we're using [Material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) to represent some data. We decided to convert it to [x-data-grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/) as it's an official grid from MUI. However, the "data" prop from **Material-Table** accepts either `any[]` or `((query: Query<{}>) => Promise<QueryResult<{}>>)` (the promise is what we're passing to data) but the equivalent in `x-data-grid` accepts only `any[]` and I've no idea how to pass in the promise so that it returns an `array` of **objects**.

Function that provides data to Material Table and it works by doing `<MaterialTable data={handleUpdate}/>`

```
const handleUpdate = (query) => {
    const refresh = Date.now();
    lastRefresh = refresh;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      updateData({ ...query, refresh }, resolve, reject)
    });
  };
```

but `<DataGrid row={handleUpdate}/>` doesn't. Any tips on how to approach this? Thank you so much in advance.